# how to store the id in environment variable from post operation in postman?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, web-api-testing

I'm unable to set the environment variable in postman TEST. 
My response body only showing 1 after to do a POST operation. In response header i get the Transfer-Encoding → chunked, Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8 etc... I don't exactly is Transfer-Encoding creating an issue?

[image: postman error screen1]

[image: postman error screen2]

```
public JsonResult CreateCustomer([FromBody]Customer customer)
    {
        try
        {
            BaseDataAccess baseDataAccess = new BaseDataAccess(_config["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);

            List<DbParameter> parametersList = new List<DbParameter>();

            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("StatementType", "Insert"));
            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("Name", customer.Name));
            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("Email", customer.Email));
            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("PrimaryPhone", customer.PrimaryPhone));
            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("AlternatePhone", customer.AlternatePhone));
            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("Address1", customer.Address1));
            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("Address2", customer.Address2));
            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("Address3", customer.Address3));
            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("City", customer.City));
            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("State", customer.State));
            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("Country", customer.Country));
            parametersList.Add(baseDataAccess.GetParameter("Zip", customer.Zip));

            return Json(baseDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery("[dbo].[CreateCustomer]", parametersList, CommandType.StoredProcedure));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191592/discussion-on-question-by-murthy-how-to-store-the-id-in-environment-variable-fro).

Comment: @murthy had you posted the POSTMAN code and responses as text people would have detected the possible problem immediatelly. Right now they'd have to a) open the image in a *new window* - it's simply unreadable now. Frankly, 90% would stop here. b) Do the same for the request. There goes another 90%. That leaves 1% of viewers. Someone now says "What's wrong with this discussion? Lets read it instead of moving or closing" and d) Decide that environment variables are irrelevant, start counting request properties, reading the code and discovering the mismatch between code and response

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there are several misunderstandings involved in this question. `ExecuteNonQuery`'s result is confused for the stored procedure's output code or result. `return Json(..)` is passed a single number but the Javascript code expects the response to contain an object. `Environment variable` doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem.

The Javascript code :

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
...
.... jsonData.customerId);
```

Expects the response to contain a JSON string containing a single object with a`customerId` attribute.

The server code though, returns just the number of rows :

```
return Json(baseDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery("[dbo].[CreateCustomer]", parametersList, CommandType.StoredProcedure));
```

[ExecuteNonQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns the number of rows affected by a query or stored procedure. Inserting one row returns 1. It *doesn't* return the stored procedure's result or output parameter(s).

This means the server effectively executes this :

```
return Json(1);
```

The response will contain a plain `1`.

To return a JSON object with a `customerId`, the code should change to :

```
var newItem=new {customerId=thatNewId;};
return Json(newItem);
```

This will return `{'customerId: 1234}`, what Javascript expects.

Without knowing what the stored procedure does, one can only guess how to extract the new ID. There are no output parameters in the C# code, so I'll assume that the ID is returnd as a single result, eg with :

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY;
```

The web app should use [ExecuteScalar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var thatNewId = baseDataAccess.ExecuteScalar("[dbo].[CreateCustomer]", 
                                              parametersList, 
                                              CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Putting it all together :

```
var thatNewId = baseDataAccess.ExecuteScalar("[dbo].[CreateCustomer]", 
                                              parametersList, 
                                              CommandType.StoredProcedure);
var newItem=new {customerId=thatNewId;};
return Json(newItem);
```

I'll just assume the POSTMAN code is correct

Comment: Great effort! but if you consider this as an answer, you should need to change the question :)

Comment: @Div that's true for at least 30% of SO questions. How many times have you gone down a rabbit hole only to discover it's the wrong hole? I probably lost half of last week doing that. There's even a name for it, [The XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and even has [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: That's indeed true! Yup aware with XY problem. Before coming down to SO, it was just theory for me; now here, I can see some practical examples :D